# Merge Vectors In APL

Tags: vector, masking, apl

Using Dyalog APL I would like to take a Mask Vector where '-' means use the original character and any other character is to replace that position in the Data Vector. So in the example below, Mask 'a' is used on Vector 'b' to create Vector 'c'.

```
┌──────┬────────┬────┐
│X--Y-Z│--34--91│-+-+│ Mask Vector a
└──────┴────────┴────┘
┌──────┬────────┬────┐
│abcdef│hijklmno│stuv│ Data Vector b
└──────┴────────┴────┘
┌──────┬────────┬────┐
│XbcYeZ│hi34lm91│s+u+│ Resultant Vector c
└──────┴────────┴────┘
```

The vectors contain strings of different lengths. I do not wish to use any Regular Expression or Search and Replace function built into APL.

I created code to perform this function, but it seems far too complicated as it is creating matrices, rotating characters around, and pulling data out of rows. I am sure there is an easier way to perform this function in APL. I am interested in seeing what more experienced APL developers come up with.

Answer (score 2):

```
mask  ← 'X--Y-Z' '--34--91' '-+-+'
data  ← 'abcdef' 'hijklmno' 'stuv'
where ← '-'≠mask
fill ← where/¨mask
(where/¨data) ← fill
data
```

The principal operation is `(where/¨data) ← fill`, which is an example of ["selective assignment"](https://help.dyalog.com/18.0/Content/Language/Primitive%20Functions/Assignment%20Selective.htm).

This operation can be more succinctly defined as an operator:

`merge ← {d←⍵ ⋄ (w/¨d)←(w←⍺⍺≠⍺)/¨⍺ ⋄ d}`

And called in the form `mask ('-' merge) data`

Comment: Thank you. So easy with "selective assignment". It took a lot of work to do it without that function.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a great way to modify data in-place is th use the At operator `@`. It can be used in a couple of different ways, but here, we'll use the pattern `substitution_data @ masking_function original_data`:

```
      mask ← 'X--Y-Z' '--34--91' '-+-+'
      data ← 'abcdef' 'hijklmno' 'stuv'
      mask {(⍺~'-')@(⍺≠'-'⍨)⍵}¨ data
┌──────┬────────┬────┐
│XbcYeZ│hi34lm91│s+u+│
└──────┴────────┴────┘
```

[Try it on TryAPL!](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=%27X--Y-Z%27%20%27--34--91%27%20%27-%2B-%2B%27%20%7B(%E2%8D%BA%7E%27-%27)%40(%E2%8D%BA%E2%89%A0%27-%27%E2%8D%A8)%E2%8D%B5%7D%C2%A8%20%27abcdef%27%20%27hijklmno%27%20%27stuv%27&run)

We use an outer loop `{`…`}¨` to process *Each* corresponding pair of elements from the mask and the data. Inside the dfn `{`…`}`, the mask is `⍺` and the data is `⍵`.

The **substitution data** consists of all the characters in `⍺` except dashes, so we remove the dashes with the *Without* function `~`.

The **masking function** is actually applied to `⍵` by the `@` operator, but it ignores its argument by way of the constant operator `⍨` which then just returns the dash character. The single dash is compared to the current `⍺` to get a mask indicating which elements to modify.

Comment: Got to love the power of APL primitives. Didn't know about the @ operator as it does not appear on the language bar in the Dyalog V18.0 I was using. I like how it is capable of performing an operation on selected elements within a vector including replacing elements with other data,